# How to debug 'Stack smashing detected'?

Tags: c++, stack-smash

I have a complex c++ code.  It's a FastCGI program, using the [FastCGI C++ Class library](http://althenia.net/fcgicc).

When I ask it for a very looooong url, I get:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./tileserve terminated
Erreur de segmentation
```

For real life applications, it's not an issue since I never use so long URLs, but this means that anyone could terminate my server... I don't like that.

Is there a tool to find out where this problem appears?  How do I use it?

### EDIT: SOLVED

I was doing this:

```cpp
int len;
char uri[200];

len = strlen(request.params[std::string("REQUEST_URI")].c_str());
printf("%d\n", len);

if (len > 200) return 1;

strcpy(uri, request.params[std::string("REQUEST_URI")].c_str());
```

Looks like `200` was too high for the `len` test.  It actually fails at `194`.

So instead I did this:

```cpp
if (len > 190) return 1;
```

Now, it's fine.

Comment: Stack trace can give you a hint.

Comment: +1 for `Erreur de segmentation`

Comment: Let me guess. The error is caused because the URL is too long for the buffer you put it in.

Comment: Check the buffers the url goes into.. checkout valgrind for the exact location of the overflow.

Comment: Don't ever use a function like `strcpy` if writing something like a webserver. This is a potential security issue. Instead use something like `strncpy` that makes  sure you don't copy too much into the buffer.

Comment: Len = 200 is too high by default.. array of 200 chars can fit a string only 199 chars long

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you read the website you will realize that this is a simple C++ wrapper over a C library.

A typical issue with C library are buffer overruns:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char buffer[16]; // ought to be sufficient

  strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
  printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Try this program:

```
> ./test "a"
a
> ./test "abcdefghijklmnoprqstuvwxyz"
???
```

Because the buffer can only contain 16 characters, the remaining characters will be written past its end. This is *stack smashing*, and **undefined behavior**.

A number of implementations of either the runtime library or your OS may detect this situation in some conditions and terminate the program.

Either *you* are doing something wrong or *the library* is.

To locate the issue, you could use Valgrind or run your program in a debugger. Alternatively, if your system allows it, you might have a memory dump at the moment the program was killed. You can also view this memory dump in a debugger.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what is the problem. The issue is to locate it...

Comment: @user1219721: oups sorry, missed that part. Use a debugger (integrated in VC++ or gdb on Linux).

Comment: Valgrind is useless here, since it does not detect stack-based memory errors - only heap memory corruption.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia: In the toy example I presented yes. In general... it's a bit more difficult: I suspect a buffer overrun but it could simply be reading a non-initialized value and using it as an offset.

Comment: @MatthieuM. +1 and removed my comments .

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Gcc got stack protector option which allows to see proper backtrace. To actually find who smasher is, one should figure out address where bad things were written to and put  breakpoint watch at that address

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like valgrind, or your compiler may have static analysis that can find places you might be overrunning buffers.

Also you can just audit your code for uses of error prone functions like strcpy and replace them with safe functions like strncpy, or better yet just use objects that manage their own memory like std::string.